# 2nd Order Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, inductor, differential

just want to check whether am i doing correctly?
How do I know when should I find Voltage ODE and when should I find current ODE?

Thank You

Update: Vc(0) shld be zero.

[image]
[image]